# Why a stored procedures which takes a join on multiple table having around 50k rows is taking long time to execute?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have around 50,000 records in all the table being joined. More or less.

But it takes around 15-20 seconds in loading.

Also, each is a primary key and joined by that.

```
Select 
            distinct H.EQHeaderID,H.EQUNR 'Equipment No', str.TPLNR 'Functional Location', H.STTXT 'Description', H.EQTYP 'Category', 
            H.DATAB 'Valid From', H.DATBI 'Valid To',

            H.SHTXT 'Technical Object Description', H.GUID,

            g.EQART 'Object Type', g.HERST 'Manufacturer', g.TYPBZ 'Model No',  
            g.SERGE 'Manufacturer Serial No', g.HERLD 'Manufacturer Country', g.BAUJJ 'Construction Year', g.BAUMM 'Construction Month',
            g.ANSDT 'Acquisition Date', g.BEGRU 'Authorization Group', g.ERDAT 'Creation Date',
            g.HZEIN 'Manufacturer Drawing Number',  g.INBDT 'Start-up Date of the Technical Object',
            g.ANSWT 'Aquisition Value',

            loc.SWERK 'Maint Plant', loc.STORT 'Location', loc.BEBER 'Plant Section',
            loc.ABCKZ 'ABC Indicator', loc.EQFNR 'Sort Field', loc.MSGRP 'Maintenance Planning Plant',

            Org.BUKRS 'Company Code', Org.ANLNR 'Asset', Org.GSBER 'Business Area', Org.KOSTL 'Cost Center', Org.PROID 'WBS Element',
            Org.GEWRK 'Work Center', Org.INGRP 'Planner group', Org.IWERK 'Maintenance Planning Plant',
            Org.KOKRS 'Controlling Area', Org.RBNR 'Catalog profile',

            str.HEQNR 'Superior Equipment', str.POSNR 'Position', str.SUBMT 'Const Type', 
            str.HEQUI 'Superordinate Equipment', str.TIDNR 'Technical Identification Number',

            ser.MATNR 'Material', Ser.SERNR 'Serial No', ser.LBBSA 'Stock Type No', ser.B_CHARGE 'Batch No', ser.B_LAGER 'Storage Location',
            ser.CHARGE 'Master Batch No',

            warr.GWLEN 'Warranty Date',

            cls.CLASS, cls.KLTXT 'Class Description', cls.KLART 'Class Type',

            h.EntryDateTime 'ReceivingDateTime', 
            Case when h.Transferred = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end 'Imported',
            h.TransferredModuleName 'Module'


            from dbo.EQ_Header h 

            left Join dbo.EQ_General g
            ON h.EQHeaderID= g.HeaderID
            left Join dbo.EQ_Location loc
            ON loc.HeaderID= h.EQHeaderID
            left Join dbo.EQ_Organizations org
            ON org.HeaderID= h.EQHeaderID
            left Join dbo.EQ_Structure str
            ON str.HeaderID= h.EQHeaderID
            left Join dbo.Eq_Classification cls
            ON cls.HeaderID= h.EQHeaderID
            left Join dbo.EQ_Serial ser
            ON ser.HeaderID= h.EQHeaderID
            left Join dbo.EQ_Warranty warr
            ON warr.HeaderID= h.EQHeaderID

            where h.EQUNR= '1231231'
            and Cast(h.EntryDateTime as Date) BETWEEN '2014-10-11' AND '2020-04-22'
            --and ISNULL(h.Transferred,0)=0
```

I have removed the fragmentation. Also, created index on EQHeaderID but still no progress.

Comment: Using `CAST` on your column `EntryDateTime` is the `WHERE` is going to have a likely impact. Also, do you need the `DISTINCT` that can be *very* costly.

Comment: Is it JUST possible that the harcoded literals you have in your where clause are, in fact, parameters?

Comment: @SMor: Yes params

Comment: @Larnu: distinct is needed but cast i have removed but still no effect

Comment: what does your execution plan say (SSMS), but i assume the main problem would be the distinct, with the number of columns there...

Comment: CAn you post the query plan please (search "Paste the Plan")? Honestly, I find it rare that `DISTINCT` is needed when you have so many columns; seems like you have a `JOIN` problem and why you "need" it.

Comment: I must admit, as well, I really recommend against the alias format `{expression} 'Alias String'`. `{Expression} AS [Alias]` or `[Alias] = {expression}` are far more readable. Literal string make for confusing code ti read.

Comment: You might suffer from [parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/). But the first step is to examine the execution plan as others have indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Can’t tell for sure without a full hands-on review, but some things that jump out for further investigation

The `DISTINCT` clause means ALL the rows have to be read and analyzed for duplicates—one by one, column by column, and there are a lot of columns in there. (What datatypes are present? Any varchar(max) or other long strings?) There are possible tricks if you can reduce the set of columns that must be `DISTINCT`.

What is the cardinality of EQ_Header.EQUNR? How many rows will  '1231231' produce? (Is the datatype correct? For example, if this is an nvarchar columns, SQL will have to cast your non-nvarchar value to nvarchar, at which point it may choose to do a table scan over all of EQ_Header.)

`Cast(h.EntryDateTime as Date) BETWEEN '2014-10-11' AND '2020-04-22'` will not make things faster, unless (a) you have an index on `Cast(h.EntryDateTime as Date)`, and (b) there’s very little data in that six-year period, which seems unlikely. A possible more efficient way to set this up might be

```
and h.EntryDateTime >= '2014-10-11' and h.EntryDateTime < '2020-04-23'
```

but, again, this probably won't make a difference.

For each row returned from EQ_Header, how many rows—from each table—do you anticipate being returned? Note that as they are all left outer joins, SQL will essentially have to loop through them all for each row found in EQ_Header—if volume is high, that might be an issue.

Comment: slight correction - replacing the casting logic from datetime to date will require a change to the upper bound (by adding a single day) to accomodate the time component.

Comment: @Smor, good catch--I got the `<` right, then forgot to increment the date.